# Running an external script with matplotlib commands in Ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I just run into a weird problem. The way I am writing my code, first I write functions on the fly in the Ipython Qt console interactively, and tweak them as necessary. Once I am satisfied with the results, I move them into a py file, to use the functions at a later time.

So, I wrote a function which is supposed to plot a histogram on screen. If I first run my py script, then call the function with the required arguments, I get an error message, which is at the very bottom of this post. If I copy and paste the function code to the qt console, and hit enter, then the function works fine after that point.

Why would this function work fine after I copy paste it to the qt console, but does not work if I directly call it after running my script with the `%run script.py` magic?

Thanks for any ideas!

Here is my function:

```
def PlotFreqHist(w_hist_list, head, span, m):
    '''
    Generates a frequency distribution plot
    '''
    if head == 30.:
        tr_cond = 'Normal'
    else:
        tr_cond = 'Congested'

    histweights = np.zeros_like(w_hist_list[0]) + 1. / w_hist_list[0].size * 100
    bmap = brewer2mpl.get_map('RdYlBu', 'diverging', 10)
    colors = bmap.mpl_colors
    mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = colors
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    ax = axes()
    plt.xlim(0.0,1.2)
    plt.ylim(0.0,6)
    plt.xlabel('Uniform Load [kips/ft]')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency [%]')
    plt.title('Frequency Distribution\n Number of Simulations = %i     Span Length = %.0fft     Traffic Condition = %s' %(m, span, tr_cond))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.02))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1.0))
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.2))
    plt.grid(b=True, which='major', linewidth=1.0)
    plt.grid(b=True, which='minor')

    for i in xrange(len(w_hist_list)):
        hist(w_hist_list[i], bins = 200, range = (0,2), normed = 0, cumulative = 0, histtype = charttype, linewidth=2.0, alpha =0.5, weights = histweights)

    plt.show()
```

And here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 779, in structured_traceback
    records = _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 245, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records  = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 1043, in getinnerframes
    framelist.append((tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 1007, in getframeinfo
    lines, lnum = findsource(frame)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 580, in findsource
    if pat.match(lines[lnum]): break
IndexError: list index out of range
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.
```

Comment: That error message is unfortunately just saying that there was an error showing the real error message. But I thought we (IPython) had fixed that bug. What version of IPython are you using?

Comment: @ThomasK hi, it turns out I had been using IPython 0.13.1, which came with Python(x,y) 2.7.2.3. I installed the latest version, and started getting the tracebacks properly. The problem was that my code was missing some import lines at the header. As far as I see all import lines (matplotlib, pylab etc.) should be properly included in the external py file to run it in IPython.

Comment: Yep, when you `%run` a script, it can't 'see' any variables you've got in IPython, though there's a `-i` option to let it see them.